# Checkbox: checkbox select all and unselect not effect on all

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, checkbox, selectall

I'm trying to do a button to check and uncheck all boxes using react.But for some reason, 'Select All' is only selecting three of them, while 'Unselect All' is only unselecting those three and selecting the rest two.

My code is as below:

```
<button type='button' className='btnSelectAll' onClick={this.selectAllOrNone}>Select All</button>

this.selectAllOrNone = () => {
            let events = document.getElementsByClassName('toDoList_checkbox')
            let btnSelectAll = document.getElementsByClassName('btnSelectAll')[0]
            console.log(events)

            for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                if (btnSelectAll.innerHTML === 'Select All') {
                    events[i].checked = true
                    btnSelectAll.innerHTML = 'Unselect All'
                }
                else if (btnSelectAll.innerHTML === 'Unselect All') {
                    events[i].checked = false
                    btnSelectAll.innerHTML = 'Select All'
                }

                console.log('btnSelectAll')
            }
        }
```

Anyone can suggest what the problem is?enter image description here

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post your HTML as [mre] in order to help us help you. Use `<>` in editor in order to make snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the buttons text on each iteration of your `for` loop, change the text after completing the `for` loop, since you change the button's text on each iteration, half will evaluate as false:

```
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    if (btnSelectAll.innerHTML === 'Select All') {
         events[i].checked = true;
    }else
    //else if (btnSelectAll.innerHTML === 'Unselect All') { //Don't need else-if
         events[i].checked = false;
    }
    
}

//Change your button text after the for loop completes
if(btnSelectAll.innerHTML === 'Select All'){
   btnSelectAll.innerHTML = 'Unselect All';
}else{
   btnSelectAll.innerHTML = 'Select All';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the button state inside the if in the loop.
This means you are checking each item differently. Try to change the "select all" button state outside the loop, just after change every items.